How does Plato's theory of forms account for change and abstraction?
I have two questions regarding Plato's theory of forms. Take apples for example.

Is there a form Apple of which all the particular apples in the world participate in? An apple is not a being, rather it becomes; so the question 'what "is" it?' doesn't seem to apply. Yet apples must have an intelligible form which allows me to comprehend an apple when I see one (or help me differentiate between a "good" apple and a "bad" apple).

I can think of two possible answers. First, there is a form Apple which is a kind of inner form (or structure) which is the same form I mentally grasp when I look at an apple at time t_1 and when I look at it at time t_2. The second possibility is that there is no form corresponding to the apple, only the universals corresponding to its qualities (e.g., redness, roundness, etc.) and whether or not an apple is good is a function of how perfect the qualities that inhere in it are.

But these universal qualities raise another problem. Is there a form corresponding to the red color of the apple? The question 'what is redness' does make sense, but redness is an abstraction from the apple as a sensible. If Redness were a form it must be an intelligible, that is, something immediately understood by my mind.

Edit: it is concerning that that this post has not gotten any upvotes and that all the comments so far have followed the same pattern, namely, assuming that because the questions are naive that the concerns they raise can be easily pushed aside. If textual evidence could be brought forth to support one interpretation or another, as an attempt toward resolving these contradictions, would that not be of interest?

There is no change in the world of Forms.

@MauroALLEGRANZA right, so the question is how can there be a form Apple given that apples change but forms do not

@MauroALLEGRANZA it seems like there is no obvious answer, so maybe you can upvote the question to help maximize the chances that someone with expertise on Plato will see it

Questions on Platonism invariably stumble on egs that are extremal strawman-arguments and then getting stumped by the strawmanness rather than serious questions. So instead of asking about the form of appleness (and the form of chairness for some reason I lot of that) try asking about the form of beauty, the form of ;gratitude, the form of love and the last — the form of the Good.  And a crucial intermediary — the form of a point, a straight line a number and so on

@SihOASHoihd Extending and adjusting the theory of forms in order to describe change and instantiation is part of the main motivation for Aristotle's Metaphysics. The kinds of questions you ask about are major concerns in that book. If you haven't looked at the Metaphysics yet, it's worth a look.

@user509184 that is an interesting way of looking at the metaphysics, but not really related to my questions

Plato's dialogues are quite difficult...
Some relevant texts are in the Parmenides:

129d If anyone then undertakes to show that the same things are both many and one—I mean such things as stones, sticks, and the like—we shall say that he shows that they are many and one, but not that the one is many or the many one; he says nothing wonderful, but only what we should all accept. If, however, as I was saying just now, he first distinguishes the abstract ideas, such as likeness and unlikeness, multitude and unity, rest and motion, and the like, and then shows that they can be mingled and separated, I should,” said he, “be filled with amazement, Zeno.

First comment: "things as stones, sticks, and the like [...] that they are many and one, but not that the one is many or the many one." Sensible things have contrasting features and they change in time, while Forms do not.
Forms are "abstract ideas, such as likeness and unlikeness, multitude and unity, rest and motion, and the like".

149d “These two ideas, greatness and smallness, exist, do they not?” “For if they did not exist, they could not be opposites of one another and could not come into being in things.” “That is obvious.”

Abstracts (i.e. Forms) must exists in order that things (sensibles) have the properties that have: sensibles change while forms do not.
An apple grows, changing in time from small to big, but smallness does not become greateness.
You can see the texts with the detailed commentary into:

Plato, Parmenides (Samuel Scolnicov editor, California UP 2003).

Regarding Aristotle criticism of Plato, see Gail Fine, On Ideas. Aristotle's Criticism of Plato's Theory of Forms (1995, Oxford University Press) (see e.g. Ch.6 Forms of Artefacts).
